# Join in 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel-5

I have 3 tables food,restaurant and categories.
I want to make join between these. I have a query to join food and categories as:

```
> $Category = DB::table('food')->select('food.Food_id','food.FoodName','food.FoodImage','food.FoodType','categories.CategoryName')->join('categories','categories.Category_id','=','food.Category_id')->where('categories.CategoryName', '=','Breakfast')->get();
```

I want to join restaurant with this. How I can do that?
My tables are:

food:

- Food_id(PK)

  FoodName

  Category_id(FK)

And category table is:

- Category_id(PK)

  CategoryName

And restaurant table is:

- Res_id

  Res_Name

  Address_loc

  Food_id(FK)

Comment: sqlserver, sqlite or mysql, which one are you using?

Comment: I am using phpmyadmin

Comment: ok, the database if mysql then :) Can you show how you tried to implement the code from my answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
$Category = DB::table('food')->select('food.Food_id','food.FoodName','food.FoodImage','food.FoodType','categories.CategoryName', 'restaurant.Res_Name')
 ->join('restaurant', 'restaurant.Food_id', '=', 'food.Food_id')
 ->join('categories','categories.Category_id','=','food.Category_id')
 ->where('categories.CategoryName', '=','Breakfast')->get();
```

You can use Food_id to join the restaurant onto food.

(Not sure if the syntax of the code is correct, but it fits to your example. Might have to change the tablename of restaurant as you seem to be switching between lower and upper case)

Comment: Can you try writing it in a single line, like in your example? You just have to add `->join('restaurant', 'restaurant.Food_id', '=', 'food.Food_id')` before the `->where('categories.CategoryName', '=','Breakfast')->get();`